# Background transfer error when uploading files to OneDrive using windows community toolkit OneDrive service

Tags: uwp, onedrive, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to upload file to OneDrive using windows community toolkit OneDrive service. I can do the uploading when my app is foreground. But when put it background, the upload progress is paused.

Now I want to transfer in background using upload operation.

But I got a 400 error request. Is there anything wrong?

[image]

```
//Background Upload
                var upload = await OneDriveServiceHelper.CreateBackgroundUploadForItemAsync(oneDriveAppFolder, file, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                upload.Priority = BackgroundTransferPriority.High;
                Progress<UploadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<UploadOperation>(UploadProgress);
                //CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken);
                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                await upload.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);


public static async Task<UploadOperation> CreateBackgroundUploadForItemAsync(OneDriveStorageFolder destinationFolder, StorageFile sourceFile, CreationCollisionOption creationCollisionOption, BackgroundTransferCompletionGroup completionGroup = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (destinationFolder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destinationFolder));
            }

            if (sourceFile == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sourceFile));
            }

            //var fileCreateNew = await destinationFolder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            return await Task.Run(
                async () =>
                {
                    var requestMessage = OneDriveService.Instance.Provider.GraphProvider.Drive.Items[destinationFolder.OneDriveItem.Id].Content.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
                    await OneDriveService.Instance.Provider.GraphProvider.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(requestMessage).AsAsyncAction().AsTask(cancellationToken);
                    var uploader = completionGroup == null ? new BackgroundUploader() : new BackgroundUploader(completionGroup);
                    foreach (var item in requestMessage.Headers)
                    {
                        uploader.SetRequestHeader(item.Key, item.Value.First());
                    }
                    uploader.SetRequestHeader("Filename", sourceFile.Name);
                    return uploader.CreateUpload(requestMessage.RequestUri, sourceFile);
                }, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: Could you share a simple sample?

Comment: Hi, @NicoZhu-MSFT, I have upload a sln to github, see https://github.com/hupo376787/BackgroundUploadSample

Comment: Do you give write authority with in one drive application profile ?

Comment: I registered my app id in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/, following guide https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/OneDrive%20Service/OneDriveCode.bind. When I click in my app, in section "Microsoft Graph Authorition", there is only "User.Read". I can't add other authority, because it pops  Insufficient permissions to perform this operation. Please allow your administrator to allow users to register applications.

Error message: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 11:01:04 GMT 4JDRK 4JDRK Df7x6

Comment: Now I can Add authority like Files.ReadWrite, Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder, Users.Read, Users.ReadWrite. But still have the 400 error.

Comment: Yep, I reproduced your issue, I think you may miss some header, Have you tried to post your file with httpclient?

Comment: I'm new to web transfer. But I can use UploadSimpleFileAsync and UploadLargeFileAsync to upload successfully, wrapped by Windows Community Toolkit, while the two methods are paused when app is background. See https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/OneDrive%20Service/OneDriveSampleHelpers.cs. My background transfer method is written following web results.

Comment: Yep,I know that, I found your blog in bo ke yuan.

Comment: Ha...Do you know how to accomplish background upload transfer. I'm stuck in this problem for several days...

Comment: In general, you could use `BackgroundUploader` to achieve that. but for OneDrive, need more parameter. Have you tried to use Fiddler to catch some info when you invoke upload method within Community Tool Kit?

Comment: I downloaded Fiddler, but don't know to to use it.. It seems messy.

Comment: The contents of the request body should be the **binary** stream of the file to be uploaded. I found this from [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content#request-body).

Comment: Not work while change to stream......

Comment: Yep, I know you used `IInputStream`, but it is different from binary stream.